# Code Igniter, how can I make pagination class use the page number instead of the offset?

Tags: php, codeigniter

using the default pagination class, and following the odeigniter user manual i fail to see how you can make the url make sense to the user?

for example: the links will look like this: < 1 2 **3** 4 5 > but the url for link 1 is

> localhost/entries/page/

when i would expect it to be

> localhost/entries/page/1

similarly on page 3 it is:

> localhost/entries/page/4

obviously it is using the offset as the 3rd segment in the uri. How can I get pagination to work using page numbers, where the link numbers actually match the 3rd uri segment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily set in the config for the pagination class:

Taken from the docs:

> By default, the URI segment will
>   use the starting index for the items you are paginating. If you prefer
>   to show the the actual page number, set this to TRUE.

So:

```
$this->load->library('pagination');

$config['base_url'] = //site_url('controller/method');
$config['total_rows'] = //get rows from model
$config['per_page'] = 10; 
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;

$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

**Extra tip**: note that if your uri segment is not the 3rd (default) you can also set which one to use (I once risked my mental sanity for this):

```
$config['uri_segment'] = 4;
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to do anything for me, i still get the offset in the url rather than the actually page number i should be on

Comment: sorry, for some reason my code igniter system pagination class was outdated and didn't have the use_page_numbers config item! Thanks!

Comment: @Jai Oh, now that I look better, you didn't specify the version you were using, I just assumed the latest (but IIRC it was there in 2.0 too). Anyway, glad you solved the problem, cheers!